# Are there tags for MySQL versions?

Tags: support, tags

Because MySQL version 8 has Windows functions like `row_number` and `lag` and also allows use of CTE, it would be important to have those tags.

SQL Server has tags like [sql-server-2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008), but I didn't find any for MySQL.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes there are:

- [mysql2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql2)
- [mysql4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql4)
- [mysql5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql5)
- [mysql-5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-5.0)
- [mysql-5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-5.1)
- [mysql-5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-5.5)
- [mysql-5.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-5.6)
- [mysql-5.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-5.7)
- [mysql6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql6)
- [mysql-8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-8.0)

Source: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1100135/mysql-version-tags

The tag editor in questions only will show you the first x most used tags. The most used version tag is [mysql2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql2) with 636 questions tagged which falls out of this list. If you want to show more tags you can always search the [Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) page.

Comment: Yes, looks like they are there. Then the problem is with the auto complete feature. Check the picture I add and you understand why was my confusion. if you write `sql-server-`  you get the sql version in the auto complete.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza That editor will only show you the first x (not sure if it is always 5) most used tags. You can always use the [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) page if you want more results.

Comment: Well if editor dont show `mysqli` or `mysqldump` when you search by `mysql-` then the `mysql-5.7` may show

Comment: the autocomplete can't read your mind. It makes sense for it to only show the top n relevant tags, as that prevents less relevant and often wrong tags from showing up.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Right, even that page only appears to show the first 36 results when you search. [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) seems the most reliable. (Recently created tags wont show up there either because SEDE doesn't use live data, but in this case that doesn't really matter.)

Comment: @KevinB I don't need auto complete read my mind. I'm searching for `mysql-` and show me 2 result without `-`

Comment: You can see pretty clearly in the dropdown that displays that `-` is ignored. For good reason imo.

Comment: [The tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) is probably your best bet, sorting by Name (rather than the default Popular). It also ignores the hyphen though.